# Still having trouble running Zelda Classic on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

So I downloaded and extracted Zelda Classic to my Downloads file on my Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit laptop. I opened the folder and clicked on zlaunch-l and nothing happened. I checked the properties and it is executable. I selected Run Software to run the zlaunch-l app again to no effect. I tried selecting it in the Terminal but it doesn't seem capable of distinguishing the space in the Zelda Classic folder name and tells me that no folder of path exists. I would like to play Zelda on my machine, but I would also like to know how to get apps I download outside of the Software Center to run. Please, somebody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zelda classic requires various 32-bit libraries that are not included with the 64-bit version of Ubuntu. Use the commands `ldd ./zlaunch-l` and `ldd ./zelda-l` to get a list of missing files, then use aptitude or a similar program to install said libraries. 
These commands should install all of the required libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libxcursor1:i386
sudo apt-get install libxpm4:i386
sudo apt-get install libasound2:i386
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install libxxf86vm1:i386
```

Comment: I was unable to use ldd ("not a dynamic executable") until I installed those packages; I presume there's a dependency in there that lets ldd recognize 32-bit binaries, but it's not installed by default.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did (BTW Thank you for showing me this. I will be offline for several days now ^^)

1. Downloaded game from http://www.zeldaclassic.com/downloads.php (Version 2.50 as you mentioned)
2. Went to the Download folder and right clicked the file and selected **Extract Here**. This should create a folder in the Download folder named **Zelda Classic**. Go to this folder from within your terminal and simply `./zelda-l`

It should start right away...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that I did not check any options to execute, only used the files the same way they arrived (No permissions were modified)

It this helps, line 48 of the `ag.cfg` file inside the Zelda Classic folder showed this

```
linux_qst_dir = /home/cyrex/Downloads/Zelda Classic/
```

So maybe that line can help. Am also running 14.04 64 Bit.

Comment: This should work perfectly. Maybe one addition: it is not necessary to use the terminal at all. After extracting, you can simply browse to the newly created "Zelda Classic" folder and double-click on `zelda-l`. That worked fine for me.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa Thanks. Yet another way to play Zelda forever!!

Comment: Tested and found to be fully functional using Zelda Classic v2.50 - Linux Version 43.1mb available at http://www.zeldaclassic.com/downloads.php Just what I needed. Another way to spend my time! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a typical path problem. It is not ridiculous at all, you just have to get used to the way of thinking ;)

If you try to launch a programme by calling it from a terminal, the system checks the `PATH` variable where to find it.

**Your `HOME` directory is not part of the search path and you might NOT want to change that for safety reasons**.

Simply try this instead:

- Open a terminal
- Change to the directory where you extracted the game using `cd GAMEPATH`
- Type `./zlaunch-l` and press return

The `./` in front of the command advises your system to not search along `PATH` but run the programme **right here** in your current working directory.

Comment: How do I change the directory?

Comment: I tried Extract Here and double clicked on zlaunch-l but nothing happened. When I use the terminal to try to access it I get the message /home/christopher/Downloads/Zelda: No such File or Directory. Am I maybe missing some software I should have installed?